# What php modules are used by my app

Tags: php, php-extension

Is there a way I can find out what modules are being used by my php application without going through thousands of lines of code?

I can get the whole list of PHP modules on current server via `php -m`, but I want to know if there is any way to find out modules required by my app in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PEAR package called [PHP_CompatInfo](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo/) that does something like that:

> Find out the minimum version and the extensions required for a piece of code to run

It's marked as no longer maintained, so there might be some problems using it with recent versions of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [`get_loaded_extensions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) or [`extension_loaded()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).